# large gap underneath floated columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a typical 3 column layout. For some reason, the middle column is creating a very large and unwanted gap between the top three and the bottom three. Is there a way to make it so that the gap between all of the container is the same?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avocyf33/)**

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html, body {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

column-container {
 width: 100%;
 background: #EEEEEE;
}

wrapper-container {
 width: 80%; 
 margin: auto;
}

column-three {
 padding: 25px;
}

.container {
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.container h2 {
 padding: 25px;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center; 
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #22313F;
}

.container:hover h2 {
 color: #22313F;
}

.container .image {
 margin: auto;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background: #22313F; 
}

.container .text {
 padding: 25px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 30px; 
}

.buy-button {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px; 
}

.buy-button a {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 25px; 
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #4ECDC4;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.buy-button a:hover {
 background: #45B5AD; 
}

column-container,
wrapper-container,
column-three {
 display: block;
}

column-three {
 float: left;
}

column-container {
 overflow: hidden;
}

wrapper-container {
 overflow: hidden; 
}

column-three {
 width: 33.33%; 
}


@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 
 column-three {
  width: 50%; 
 }
  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 
 column-three {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
 wrapper-container {
  width: 90%; 
 }
 
 .container .text {
  display: none; 
 }
 
 .buy-button {
  margin-top: 25px; 
 }
 
}
```

```html
<column-container>
 <wrapper-container>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft I</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">For ages, the fallen titan Sargeras plotted to scour all life from Azeroth. To this end, Sargeras possessed the human sorcerer Medivh.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft II</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The human nation of Stormwind had fallen before the Horde. Knight Champion Anduin Lothar gathered the scattered remnants of the human army and led the refugees north</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft III</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft I</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft II</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft III</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
    </wrapper-container>
</column-container>
```

Comment: On your fourth `column-three` you need to clear the float.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<wrapper-container>` for every 3 `<column-three>` So that issue will not come

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box; 
}

html, body {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

column-container {
 width: 100%;
 background: #EEEEEE;
}

wrapper-container {
 width: 80%; 
 margin: auto;
}

column-three {
 padding: 25px;
}

.container {
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.container h2 {
 padding: 25px;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center; 
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #22313F;
}

.container:hover h2 {
 color: #22313F;
}

.container .image {
 margin: auto;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background: #22313F; 
}

.container .text {
 padding: 25px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 30px; 
}

.buy-button {
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-right: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px; 
}

.buy-button a {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 25px; 
 text-decoration: none;
 background: #4ECDC4;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.buy-button a:hover {
 background: #45B5AD; 
}

column-container,
wrapper-container,
column-three {
 display: block;
}

column-three {
 float: left;
}

column-container {
 overflow: hidden;
}

wrapper-container {
 overflow: hidden; 
}

column-three {
 width: 33.33%; 
}


@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
 
 column-three {
  width: 50%; 
 }
  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 
 column-three {
  width: 100%; 
 }
 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 
 wrapper-container {
  width: 90%; 
 }
 
 .container .text {
  display: none; 
 }
 
 .buy-button {
  margin-top: 25px; 
 }
 
}
```

```html
<column-container>
 <wrapper-container>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft I</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">For ages, the fallen titan Sargeras plotted to scour all life from Azeroth. To this end, Sargeras possessed the human sorcerer Medivh.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft II</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The human nation of Stormwind had fallen before the Horde. Knight Champion Anduin Lothar gathered the scattered remnants of the human army and led the refugees north</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft III</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
      </wrapper-container>
      <wrapper-container>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft I</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft II</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
        <column-three>
         <div class="container">
             <h2>Warcraft III</h2>
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">The demonic Burning Legion prepare to launch their long-awaited assault on the mortal world. Survival is a matter of strategy.</div>
                <div class="buy-button">
                 <a href="#">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </column-three>
    </wrapper-container>
</column-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/avocyf33/1/)

I have added a `<div>` after our third column as below

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

The reason why there is a large blank space is that, for your columns, you have specified `float:left` which has to be cleared after every three columns.

For clearing that we use a style `clear:both`

Read more about it in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you floats aren't clearing correctly, because their heights aren't all the same. The fourth one sort of hooks on the second one, because it is sticking out (a bit hard to explain in my limited english)

The cleanest solution imo would be to add something like this to your css:

```
column-three:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear:both;
}
```

This will force the first element of a row to start all the way to the left.

And since your layout is responsive, inside your 2 column media query you could add this:

```
column-three:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear:both;
}
```